# Why does overloading operator<< to print Eigen class member result in a segfault?

Tags: c++, eigen, member, cout

For the following struct

```
struct TestClass {
  TestClass() : mat(Eigen::Matrix3i::Zero()) {}
  Eigen::Matrix3i mat;
};
```

I would like to have an overloaded `operator<<` to print the `mat` member to `std::cout`. I tried

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const TestClass& object) {
    out << object.mat;
}
```

This results in a segfault. Can anyone explain to me why?

A minimum working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

struct TestClass {
  TestClass() : mat(Eigen::Matrix3i::Zero()) {}    
  Eigen::Matrix3i mat;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const TestClass& object) {
  out << object.mat;
}

int main() {
  TestClass testObject;

  std::cout << testObject.mat << "\n\n"; // This works fine.
  std::cout << testObject << '\n'; // This results in a segfault.

  return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with g++ version 7.3.0 and Eigen version 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You must return the `std::ostream` reference from the operator overload implementation, e.g. `return out << object.mat;`. Non-void functions not returning anything are usually tagged with some compiler warnings, it might be worth enabling these (e.g. `-Wall -pedantic`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The return value of the overloaded `operator<<` is `std::ostream&`. However, you are not returning anything from it.

Do the following:

```
out << object.mat;
return out;
```

or alternatively,

```
return out << object.mat;
```

Comment: Or just `return out << object.mat;`